# Get Excel VBA Application.InputBox Range by mouse left click and drag - Bind to ONE column only?

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I have edited this post to make it a little clearer.

I have code that prompts a user to select a range by mouse left click and drag
and then copies the content of one cell on a different sheet to each cell in the range.

I now need to bind the macro to only Column A so that if a user selects any range or cell in any other column then the macro will not run and gives an error message like "you have selected a invalid region please try again" and then brings up the selection box again so a user can make a selection only in Column A

```
Public Sub SelectRange()
  Dim aRange As Range
  Dim cel As Range
      
  On Error Resume Next
    Sheets("Sheet2").Select
    Columns("A2:A").Select
  Set aRange = Application.InputBox(prompt:="Enter range - Click And Drag To Select", Type:=8)
        aRange.Formula = "=Sheet1!A2"
    If aRange Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "Operation Cancelled"
  Else
    aRange.Select
  End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Nothing wrong with the code,, is doing every thing  is been written for,,, U have not included any code to Copy cell and Paste,, [Edit] your post and make changes to avoid negative votes !!.

Comment: This is quit confusing,, `The idea is that **once a range has been selected** the VBA would then copy the content of **one cell** on a different worksheet into each cell within the range that the user selected.,, be specific that U wanna to copy RANGE or A Cell only and Paste into Range as selected in ROWs or COLUMNs !!

Comment: When you select an area, just need to continue with the copy directive. Please share more sample code.

Comment: Rajesh S - I was specific. A user selects a range of cells on one sheet and the macro fills those cells with the value from a cell on another sheet.

Comment: @Kenny,,, check the code I've posted,, exactly working as your need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're on the right track. But you need to decide whether you want to:

a) fill the selected range with the value in the cell from the other sheet (as you said in your description), OR

b) set the formula of the range to *point* to the cell in the other sheet (which is what your code is doing)

Regardless, you can use the following. Just comment/uncomment the appropriate code in the Else block appropriately.

```
Public Sub SelectRange()
    Dim aRange As Range
    Dim msgresult As Integer
    
    
TryAgain:
    On Error Resume Next 'go to the next line if the inputbox is nothing (X or Cancel)
    Set aRange = Application.InputBox(prompt:="Select a range of cells in column A", Type:=8, Title:="SuperUser")
    On Error GoTo 0 'resets the onerror action
    
    'if they haven't selected something
    'if they've selected more than one column
    'if they've selected any column other than the first column
    If aRange Is Nothing Or aRange.Columns.Count > 1 Or aRange.Column > 1 Then
      
        If MsgBox("You must only select cells in column A!" & vbCrLf & _
                "Do you want to try again?" _
                , vbYesNo _
                , "SuperUser") = vbYes Then
            GoTo TryAgain
        Else
            Exit Sub
        End If
                
    
    Else 'they selected a valid range
      
        aRange = Sheet2.Range("A2") 'fill the selected range with the value from this cell
        'OR:
        'aRange.Formula2 = "=Sheet2!$A$2" 'set the formula of the selected to point towards this cell
      
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Owen, Thank you for your code which works really well but I have discovered a couple of issues when testing it out and I have been unable to solve them myself. Researching brings up so many different ways of handling errors and I am unsure of the right way to do it.

Run sub.
1. At prompt user left clicks and drags down to select a range but then clicks either Cancel or top right X button gives error box `Run-time error '424' Object required.` Debug highlights "  `Set aRange = Application.InputBox(prompt:="Select a range of cells in column A", Type:=8, Title:="SuperUser")"`

Comment: 2. At prompt user does not select a range but then clicks either Cancel or top right X button it gives the same error as above.
3. When a user selects a range outside of column A and the “You must only select cells in column A!” message box pops up, when a user clicks on “OK” can the ` “Set aRange = Application.InputBox(prompt:="” ` then reopen so the user can try again without have to re-run the macro?

Comment: @Kenny please see edited Code.

Answer (score 1):

Give this a try:

```
Public Sub SelectRange()
    Dim aRange As Range, s As String
    Dim Intersection As Range
    
    Sheets("Sheet2").Select
    On Error GoTo errr
    Set aRange = Application.InputBox(prompt:="Enter range - Click And Drag To Select", Type:=8)
    Set Intersection = Intersect(aRange, Range("A:A"))
    
    s = "=Sheet1!A2"
    
    If aRange Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "Operation Cancelled"
        Exit Sub
    End If
    If Intersection Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "Operation Cancelled"
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    Intersection.Formula = s
    Exit Sub
errr:
    On Error GoTo 0
    MsgBox "Operation Cancelled"
    Exit Sub
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

*This Macro restricts the user to Copy data from Column A only, in case of wrong selection, prompts and allows to re-select data from Column A, and finally Copies data from specific sheet's single cell and Pastes into selected range in Column A of previous sheet.*

```
Public Sub SelectAndCopyRange()
   
Dim aRange As Range
   
OperationCancelled:
On Error Resume Next
   
   Set aRange = Application.InputBox(prompt:="Select from column A only ", Type:=8)
   
   If aRange Is Nothing Or aRange.Columns.Count > 1 Or aRange.column > 1 Then
   If MsgBox("Operation cancelled, Invalid selection!,," & vbCrLf & _
                "Like to select again?" _
                , vbYesNo _
                , "New Data Selection") = vbYes Then
                
            GoTo OperationCancelled
            Else
            Exit Sub
        End If
        
   Else
      
        aRange = MySheet.Range("A1")
   
   End If
  
  Application.CutCopyMode = False

End Sub
```